# Dagger and Android context qualifiers

Tags: android, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dagger

I've been using Dagger in my projects recently while using these examples as guides:

https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples

But there's a thing I can't comprehend in them. They use `@ForActivity` and `@ForApplication` qualifiers to explicitly differentiate between those types of `Context`, but they never @Inject them in any dependency? what is up with that? is it an overlook in the example?. If so it is quite misleading.

How would I go about injecting them in any dependency then? Would `@Inject Dependency dependency` suffice and it would resolve the correct type by its own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inject the context in @ForActivity case you have to:

```
@Inject @ForActivity Context context;
```

Here is a post which explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27343567/3929577

It's the same result that with @Named annotation.

You can use this in your module:

```
@Provides @Singleton @Named("foractivity") Context provideActivityContext() {
  return activity;
}
```

And then use that:

```
@Inject @Named("foractivity") Context context;
```